# std::cin skips characters(input 1+2+3+4...)

Tags: c++

I have a problem.When the input of my program is 1+2+3+4+5... std::cin skips the '+'es and i can't store them anywhere(let's say its '-' or '*' or '/').I want to make a calculator.I'll give a smaller code example of what i mean.Hope someone will be able to explain it to me.Thanks
   `

```
double values;
    char operations;
    while (true) {
        if (std::cin >> values) {
            std::cout << values;
            continue;
        }
        else {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin >> operations;
            std::cout << operations;
        }
    }
```

`
For example when the input is 1+2+3+4+5(written in one line) the output is 12345 and it should be 1+2+3+4+5.The program never does the else part of the if.I use continue there because in the "bigger" version of this i have to return an object which is a value or an operation.

Comment: Positive numbers have an optional + sign in front of them.

Comment: and isn't there a way i can store '+'? i even tried with spaces between the numbers and +.With - it works yeah.Thanks btw

Comment: You'd fare better if you read a whole string and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Character (such as '+') cannot be stored in a variable of the double type. Thus they are thrown away. If you want to be able to get the whole line, you'll need to use a std::string.

Then, if you are building a calculator, you'll need to go through the string and separating it's components into smaller subcomponent and calculate them accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

There must be an run-time error message displayed too with it as your loop is never ending. you should take an char variable too and add else

```
if(cin>>ch) cout<<ch else  break
```

statement.

Comment: The whole answer is not being shown anyway add else if (cin>>ch)and else break;

Comment: yeah i know about the never ending while.I put it like that just because i wanted to test my method.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to get the line:

```
std::string line;

std::getline( std::cin, line );
```

Comment: You can not store "+" in your double variable (values)